# In One Night Ultimate Alien, can neutral roles win if the Synthetic Alien dies?

Tags: one-night-ultimate-alien

If you have a game of ONUA where the Synthetic Alien gets killed, can the Mortician and Blob still win? If the Blob keeps its whole blob alive, and/or if the Synthetic Alien was neighbor to the Mortician, do those roles still win?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can find, this is what the rulebook says for the Synthetic Alien (copied from a BGG thread):

> The Synthetic Alien wakes up with the Aliens. Even though he is an Alien, he has a different winning condition. Due to the self-awareness he is programmed with, he realizes that his advanced technology is too powerful for the aliens to wield, and too dangerous for the villagers to have, so he only wins if he dies. If the Synthetic dies, everyone on the alien and villager teams lose.

Since only the villager and alien teams are named, I would say that the roles not associated with either can still win regardless of what happens with the SA.